# How does self.tk.call work in the Text widget source code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter for a data structures class and I'd like to use the text widget as part of a project. The prof asked what structure I was using and I realized I didn't know how tkinter built a container around the text widget.

I dug around in the source code a little bit, in `__init__.py` there's this section:

```py
class Text(Widget, XView, YView):
    """Text widget which can display text in various forms."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Construct a text widget with the parent MASTER."""

    """ snipped stuff """

    def get(self, index1, index2=None):
        """Return the text from INDEX1 to INDEX2 (not included)."""
        return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
```

I thought that if I was able to dig into the code I'd be able to figure out what is running under the hood, but I hit a snag. I cannot figure out why everything is running this self.tk.call(self._w, 'whatever', ...) in all the functions.

Why is it calling this other function "call" and where is "call"?

In short answer terms I'm interested in knowing where get is being called from so I can figure out what kind of container is being used for the text, but now I'm also broadly interested in why there's a whole bunch of calls to this "call" function in all of the source code as well. It isn't just the text widget that does this. I couldn't figure out where "call" was going. Appreciate any direction or guidance down that path as well.

Comment: NONE of Tkinter is actually implemented in Python - the actual GUI (Tk) is implemented in the Tcl programming language.  Tkinter embeds a Tcl interpreter, available as `tk` from any widget; the `.call()` method submits command lines to that interpreter, which is basically the only way that anything GUI-related actually happens.

Comment: So if I wanted to see how the container is implemented I'd have to.... know some TCL and see the Tcl source?

Comment: The container is the widget...

Comment: Yes, the python object is also a container with all the baggage that has. I was using container to mean the data structure that holds the text in the widget. Whatever data type that member is. Some kind of linked list, or a tree, or whatever.

Comment: In the documentation it is stated *Text is represented internally with a modified B-tree structure that makes operations relatively efficient even with large texts.* - if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thank you, that does help. If you want to post that as an answer I can select it. I did say that was the short answer I was looking for. I may also dig deeper to find out exactly what was done to make it a modified b-tree as well, but no one else needs to dive that deep!

Comment: @Mattamue found the source code for you and included it in the answer.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thanks! I happened to stumble on that too. I know some c++ so at least I can make sense of this better than Tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarized comments, to preserve for future interest:

[@jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper), pointed out:

> NONE of Tkinter is actually implemented in Python - the actual GUI
> (Tk) is implemented in the Tcl programming language. Tkinter embeds a
> Tcl interpreter, available as tk from any widget; the .call() method
> submits command lines to that interpreter, which is basically the only
> way that anything GUI-related actually happens.

OP, specified his question with:

> I was using container to mean the data structure that holds the text
> in the widget. Whatever data type that member is. Some kind of linked
> list, or a tree, or whatever.

And the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.html#M195) states:

> Text is represented internally with a modified B-tree structure that
> makes operations relatively efficient even with large texts. Tags are
> included in the B-tree structure in a way that allows tags to span
> large ranges or have many disjoint smaller ranges without loss of
> efficiency. Marks are also implemented in a way that allows large
> numbers of marks. In most cases it is fine to have large numbers of
> unique tags, or a tag that has many distinct ranges.

The actual B-Tree source code is on [github](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/3528a7dc2c54d77374454e8e8619a7ad513f247c/generic/tkTextBTree.c) for further examinations